# Approximation formula for $f'(x_0)$ using Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, interpolation

To derive a formula for an approximation of $f'(x_0)$ using Taylor's theorem, in Section 4.2, pp.$188-190$ of the book Numerical Analysis by Burden and Faires, they use the following arguments:

---

$$3f'(x_0)=\frac{2}{h}[f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0 - h)] -\frac{1}{4h}[f(x_0 + 2h) - f(x_0 - 2h)]-\frac{h^4}{30}f^{(5)}(\xi_1)+\frac{2h^4}{15}f^{(5)}(\xi_2), $$
$\xi_1, \xi_2\in [x_0-2h,x_0+2h]$ come from the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Even if $f^{(5)}$ is continuous on $[x_0 — 2h, x_0 + 2h]$, the Intermediate Value Theorem
cannot be applied because here we have the difference of terms involving $f^{(5)}$. However, an alternative method can be used to show that $f^{(5)}(\xi_1)$ and  $f^{(5)}(\xi_2)$ can still be replaced by a common value $f^{(5)}(\xi)$, yielding
$$f'(x_0)=\frac{1}{12h}[8f_(x_0 + h) - 8f(x_0 - h)-f(x_0 + 2h) + f(x_0 - 2h)]+\frac{h^4}{30}f^{(5)}(\xi).$$

---

My question: I tried to figure out what 'the alternative method' they mentioned above is? Could you please explain why they can get the existence of the number $\xi$ here? Thank you so much.

Comment: This might be the derivation ("the alternative method") you are looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-point_stencil#1D_first_derivative

Comment: @Winther: The derivation on Wikipedia looks like the same as in the book. It doesn't explain why we have $\xi$ in the remainder part.

Comment: The important part for these formulas is that they provide a *bound* for the error. If you rephrase it this way its much easier to see this. In your formula you can write $|f’(x) - \ldots| = \ldots$ (sum of the two $\xi$-terms) where for the RHS you can use the triangle inequality to show that its bounded by the maximum value of $|f^{(5)}(x)h^4|/30$ which gives you the desired bound. Another approach here is to do the expansion to one higher order (see “Error estimate” in the link) to get that the error if $f^{(5)}(x)h^4/30 + \mathcal{O}(h^5)$ which is practically the same thing.